# Object of byte[] to byte[] in C#

Tags: c#, byte

I have this code in C#:

```
Object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
reader.GetValues(values);
```

now, one of my data is a `byte[]` (hence, `System.Byte[]` ?).
My question is, how can I get the `byte[]` data from that `object`?

I want to convert it to `base64` later.

I tried

```
(byte[])values[i]
```

but it doesn't work. I think I only got the `byte[]` value of the object itself.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: What do you mean by `byte[] data`? Do you mean the memory address? Or the serialized object?

Comment: I think it's an image but I don't know coz it's from a Dentrix DB.

Comment: You'd better figure out how it's stored then, because now the question is unanswerable.

Comment: I'll ask Dentrix Support about your question. Thanks @Rob. What if it's a serialized object?

Comment: If it were serialized, you would have to find out which serialization format its using (it might be the built in binaryformatter class, but thats not guaranteed, especially for images)

Comment: I'll update this question once I get a response from support. thanks @Rob

Comment: Check the type of the `values[i]` first. It could be `DBNull` for NULL value, or some DB-specific type. When you know the type, you'll know how to convert it.

Comment: @Rob, it's a serialized object.

Answer (score 0):

try Convert.ToByte()

here is the reference 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7x4400t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I already tried that it will say cannot convert from byte to byte[]

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of type when you declare this?

```
Type type = values[i].GetType();
```

Because I tried this and it worked fine:

```
byte[] a = new byte[] { 49, 50 };
Object[] values = new object[5];
values[0] = "aaa";
values[1] = a;
byte[] c = (byte[])values[1];
```